# android - xml preference screen depending on a condition

Tags: android, xml, conditional-statements, hardware, android-preferences

I need to have a `PrefrenceScreen` for every feature of my app.

There are some features that depend on the device hardware, and I need to check if the device supports the hardware (for example - `Temperature Sensor`).

My **Preferences Screens** are in an xml:

```
<PreferenceScreen
    android:summary="@string/pref_title_call_alert_settings"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar"
    android:title="@string/pref_title_call_alert">
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="@string/call_alert_is_active_key"
        android:summary="@string/call_alert_summary"
        android:title="@string/pref_title_active" />
    <PreferenceCategory android:title="@string/pref_title_settings">
        <RingtonePreference
            android:defaultValue="content://settings/system/notification_sound"
            android:dependency="@string/call_alert_is_active_key"
            android:key="@string/call_alert_notifications_ringtone_key"
            android:ringtoneType="notification"
            android:showDefault="true"
            android:title="@string/pref_title_ringtone" />
        <SwitchPreference
            android:defaultValue="true"
            android:dependency="@string/call_alert_is_active_key"
            android:key="@string/call_alert_notifications_vibrate_key"
            android:title="@string/pref_title_vibrate" />
        <ListPreference
            android:defaultValue="10"
            android:dependency="@string/call_alert_is_active_key"
            android:entries="@array/frequency_entries"
            android:entryValues="@array/frequency_values"
            android:key="@string/call_alert_notifications_frequency_key"
            android:summary="%s"
            android:title="@string/pref_title_frequency" />
        <ListPreference
            android:defaultValue="00:30"
            android:dependency="@string/call_alert_is_active_key"
            android:entries="@array/call_alert_time_entries"
            android:entryValues="@array/call_alert_time_values"
            android:key="@string/call_alert_notifications_time_key"
            android:summary="%s"
            android:title="@string/pref_title_time_until" />
    </PreferenceCategory>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

I want to have another `PrefrenceScreen` similar to this but only if the device supports a certain hardware.

Can I do that?

Comment: I don't think so, bro. It is impossible.

Comment: But I don't know why you are choosing this way for your app. You can simply check if Temperature Sensor is available or not. Make a preference in the main preference screen. If sensor is supported then make that prerelease clickable and if is not supported then make it not clickable

Comment: Yes I actually think that's the best to do it, thanks!

Comment: Thanks for this question, was thinking about the same, although I was looking for dependencies on other preferences e.g. only show subordinate preferences when master is true. back to the drawing board on this for me. :)